# Pass List of dictionary to asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

So i have a ViewModel which contains list of dictionary property

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Dictionary<int, bool>> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

I trying to get back this model from view and all time it returns list with null items.

```
@Html.Hidden(String.Format("Columns[{0}][{1}].Key", i, firstItem.Id), firstItem.Id)
@Html.CheckBox(String.Format("Columns[{0}][{1}].Value", i, firstItem.Id), Model.Columns[i][firstItem.Id])
```

This doesnt work.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Columns[i][firstItem.Id])
```

This doesnt work too.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel is very complex because it contains nested collections, i think there is no way to bind input values to model using default model binders. You should create your custom model binder, i tried to implement custom model binder, here is my implementation ListDictionary model binder:

**Custom Model binder**

```
    public class ListDictionaryModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var resultList = new List<Dictionary<int, bool>>();
            var forms = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
            var regex = new Regex(@"(true,)?false");
            var result =
                forms.AllKeys.Select(x => new {key = x, value = forms[x]}).Where(x => x.key.Contains("Columns")).ToList();
            result.ForEach(x =>
                               {
                                   var matches = regex.Matches(x.value);
                                   var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
                                   for (var i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                                   {
                                       var value = matches[i].ToString() == "true,false" ? true : false;
                                       dictionary.Add(i, value);
                                   }
                                   resultList.Add(dictionary);
                               });
            return resultList;
        }
    }
```

**Usage example**

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //example data
            var viewModel = new ViewModel
                                      {
                                          Columns = new List<Dictionary<int, bool>>
                                                        {
                                                            new Dictionary<int, bool> {{1, false}, {2, false}},
                                                            new Dictionary<int, bool> {{1, false}, {2, false}}
                                                        }
                                      };

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel)
        {
            //viewModel - contains values of user input
            return View();
        }
```

Index view:

```
@model RepositoryTestProject.ViewModels.ViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ViewModel</legend>


@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Columns,"_ColumnEdit")

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Partial views: (you should create "EditorTemplates" folder in "/Views/Shared" and put partial templates to folder)

_ColumnEdit partial view:

```
@model List<Dictionary<int,bool>>

@for(int i =0; i < Model.Count();i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>Model[i],"_DictEdit")
}
```

_DictEdit partial view:

```
@model Dictionary<int, bool>

@for(int i =0; i < Model.Count();i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>Model.ElementAt(i).Value)
}
```

need registration your model binder in global.asax

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(List<Dictionary<int,bool>>), new ListDictionaryModelBinder());
```

In the end you can be able get your values in controller like this:

[image]